# QRadioButton how add a selection check?

Tags: python, pyside2, qradiobutton

On a selection check false i try to prevent the selection of that radiobutton. But it does get selected anyway, even with singleshot timer:

```
class MyQWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        ...


        self.ui.buttonGroup.buttonPressed.connect(self.is_init)

    def is_init(self, button): 
        if True: #some check here to prevent selection of it
            print('no select')
            QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: button.setChecked(False))
```

EDIT:
Assume a button group, i try to intercept the press call (not clicked) to not select that radio button if a custom test is false (`if True: #some check`), but i cannot prevent the button from being selected also i set it to `False`, how do abort the selection of the clicked/pressed radio button if a condition is not met?

Comment: I don't understand you, explain yourself better, also provide a [mre]

Comment: i have added an explanation

Comment: From what I understand you want that if a button is pressed and if certain conditions are met then you must change its status to False regardless of its current state, am I correct?

Comment: yes, anway the state, its false if a keypress happens + condition = not select readiobutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by:

- A [`QButtonGroup`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html) is by default [`exclusive`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#exclusive-prop) which implies that a button will always be selected causing the [`setChecked(False)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#checked-prop) not to work since it would imply having no button pressed, so there is to enable and disable that property in the change.
- The change of state does not occur in the pressed but in the released so you must use the [`buttonReleased`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#buttonReleased) signal.

Considering the previous one in the next part I show a MWE:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.buttonGroup = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self)
        self.buttonGroup.buttonReleased.connect(self.on_buttonReleased)

        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        for i in range(4):
            button = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(f"button-{i}")
            lay.addWidget(button)
            self.buttonGroup.addButton(button)

    @QtCore.Slot(QtWidgets.QAbstractButton)
    def on_buttonReleased(self, button):
        if True:
            self.buttonGroup.setExclusive(False)
            button.setChecked(False)
            self.buttonGroup.setExclusive(True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(640, 240)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thats exactly the point, since exclusive i use `keyPressed` to not change a buttongroup with 'exactlyone' selected unless its valid. in your example i would have none selected. But i try to keep the last valid radiobutton selected, thats why i intercept earlier before selecting another button (and manually keeping history is meh).